# How to force my Footer section to be in the center

Tags: html, css

I have the following which is responsible to display the footer and the end of the page:-

```
<footer>
 <p> &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My Group </p>

        </footer>
```

Currently the footer is being displayed to the left side of the page, but i want to force it to be located at the center of the page. can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Comment: This is probably going to have an onslaught of answers... but are you doing anything special like absolutely positioning it? Or inside of anything? Or is `<footer>` at the root of `<body>`?

Answer (score 3):

just add this to your css

```
footer {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you Want to center the text in the footer you have to do that:

```
 footer p{
     text-align:center;
 }
```

If you want to center the footer container, you have to define a with for that, and then use the margins to center it.

```
 footer{
     width:900px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
 }
```